# refresh token if expired by multiple calls

Tags: dart, http, asynchronous

In flutter, once the api call receive 401, then I will attempt to call refesh-token API to refresh token. However, in some situation it may have more than 1 async call, so it will call refesh-token API, while changing the token. I set a boolean which indicate it is refreshing, it can be make one refresh token call only. However, it cannot be retry the API request after grant a valid token. is there are any way to do that? If the boolean flag for refresh token is false, it won't call again but it will retry the post/get request even the refreshJwt() not yet finish

httpService.dart

```
Future<http.Response> post({
required String path,
Map? body,
String? contentType,
 }) async {

final uri = Uri.parse(path);
final encoded = body != null ? jsonEncode(body) : null;

var response = await http.post(
  uri,
  body: encoded,
);

if (response.statusCode == 401) {
    await Future.wait(refreshJwt());
    //this will trigger retry, but some of the get request will call refreshJwt() also, that's the problem.
    response = await http.post(
      uri,
      body: encoded,
    );
  }
return response;
```

}